# How to create a rough boundary/contour around a binary raster?

Tags: qgis, boundaries, binary

I want to create a very rough boundary or a contour around the below attached raster.

[image: Binary raster of a classified field]

It should mainly contain the "big" black pattern without the smaller black spots but with the white spots inside. Does anyone have an idea what I could do to surround the black pattern roughly? With the "Vector Geometry -> boundary" tool I could only achieve this detailed boundary what is too exact.

[image: Exact boundary]

Comment: Have you tried buffering and then debuffering?

Comment: Draw/digitize it manually

Comment: Selecting the "big" feature and create a Buffer around it helped me to set the right boundary (boundary tool) around the main area

Answer (score 1):

Start an editing session on your resulting polygons.  Manually select the 'big' polygon.  Use the Select by Location tool  under the Vector-Research menu to select those polygons inside the big polygon.  Something like the example below where you substitute Waterbodies for your polygon data.

[image]

Use the invert selection tool to invert the selection thus highlighting those polygons outside of the big polygon.

[image]

Delete the selected records.